# Global transaction in Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Is there a way to imitate global transaction in Spring if the transaction spawns multiple threads. I know it is not really possible in Spring, but was thinking perhaps there are some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't provide transaction support; it merely ties into existing mechanisms (JTA, local transactions, mock transactions). So you're at the mercy of whatever underlying transaction you're using.

If you're in an application server, some of them allow parallel processing to be performed within the container. A container-managed thread pool has the advantage of propogating container resources (JNDI Contexts, transactions, etc.) to other threads.

WebSphere and WebLogic, for instance, use the WorkManager API: http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/28815/0 
though I seem to recall that Java EE 6 now has support for thread pools (not sure about this, though).

Answer (score 0):

Usually Transaction and other contexts are kept in ThreadLocal by container and it's available to every method during Thread execution. If you will use WorkManager API you would need to check if your vendor support Transactional context propagation to async jobs (it's not required by specification [from what I recall](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/javadocs/commonj/work/WorkManager.html)).

Another alternative could be to look at Spring's [custom bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s04.html) - you could try to implement custom scope for your operation and store Transactional context there. It might be not trivial though.

On more general note it doesn't sound right to need transactional scope propagation to async threads - usually async operations are either CPU intensive or long lived and perhaps could be better re-implemented without a need for transaction.